# how do I capture something after something else? like a referer=someString

Tags: javascript, regex

I have ref=Apple
and my current regex is

```
    var regex = /ref=(.+)/;
    var ref = regex.exec(window.location.href);
    alert(ref[0]);
```

but that includes the ref=

now, I also want to stop capturing characters if a & is at the end of the ref param. cause ref may not always be the last param in the url.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `ref[1]` instead.

This accesses what is captured by group 1 in your pattern.

Note that there's almost certainly a better way to do key/value parsing in Javascript than regex.

#### References

- [regular-expressions.info/Brackets for Capturing](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html)

Comment: ref[0] s a reference to the whole string that was searched. I also agree that parsing key value pairs are much smoother using String.split. Ext-JS has a method called urlDecode that turns urls into a key/value object.  And can be used like var params=Ext.urlDecode(location.search); http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/docs/source/Ext.html#method-Ext-urlDecode

Answer (score 3):

You'll want to split the url parameters, rather than using a regular expression.

Something like:

```
var get = window.location.href.split('?')[1];
var params = get.split('&');
for (p in params) {
    var key = params[p].split('=')[0];
    var value = params[p].split('=')[1];

    if (key == 'ref') {
        alert('ref is ' + value);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Capture only word characters and numbers:

```
var regex = /ref=(\w+)/;
var ref = regex.exec(window.location.href);
alert(ref[1]);
```

Capture word characters, numbers, - and _:

```
var regex = /ref=([\w_\-]+)/;
var ref = regex.exec(window.location.href);
alert(ref[1]);
```

[More information about Regular Expressions (the basics)](http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html)

Comment: Funny. I always forget about that, and I always discover it afterwards :p

Answer (score 1):

You are using the ref wrong, you should use ref[1] for the `(.+)`, `ref[0]` is the whole match.
If `&` is at the end, modify the regexp to `/ref=([^&]+)/`, to exclude `&`s.
Also, make sure you urldecode (`unescape` in JavaScript) the match.

Answer (score 0):

try this regex pattern ref=(.*?)&

This pattern will match anything after ref= and stop before '&'

To get the value of m just use following code:

var regex = /ref=(.*?)&/;

var ref = regex.exec(window.location.href);

alert(ref[1]);